# Examples of sequentially accessing data to avoid cache miss?

Tags: caching

I'm learning about how caching works and how to avoid cache miss. In most resources online I've read, the only tip they have is that "to avoid cache miss, try to access data sequentially". The statement is kind of vague to me. I would love to see some examples to see the tip in action, and perhaps some more detailed tips as well.

Thanks in advance!